# How to choose multiple service when installing laravel/sail on existing an Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

How can I choose multiple services when running `php artisan sail:install`?

When I run it, I get this prompt asking me to choose services but I can't select more than one option. When I chose `redis`, it scaffolded the app with `redis` only.

```
$ php artisan sail:install
Which services would you like to install? [mysql]:
  [0] mysql
  [1] pgsql
  [2] mariadb
  [3] redis
  [4] memcached
  [5] meilisearch
  [6] minio
  [7] mailhog
  [8] selenium
> 3

Sail scaffolding installed successfully.
```

I tried using `[0,3,5,7,8]` but it never worked. How can I choose multiple options? I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't need to specify the service options as an array, just a comma separated string.

So in your example, you only need to do:

```
0,3,5,7
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides [@Peppermintology](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67934419/458204)'s answer, you can also type the names of the services you want to install as a comma-separated string like this:

```
mysql,redis,meilisearch,mailhog,selenium
```